# UITableView Load records with pagination by removing existing records

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, lazy-loading

Actually I want to show records in `UITableView`, total number of records may exceed **100 Thousand**. So I am loading these records in chunks of **100 records** every time when users reaches scrolling upto 70% records(row no.70).

I don't want to keep existing chunk of records in memory, So initially I am loading 2 chunks of 100 records, and when user scroll reaches to Row no.170, I remove first 100 records and loading 1 chunk of 100 records.

But my problem is how do I reset value of `indexPath`? as currently its value is 170, but after loading new chunk of 100 records and removing first 100 records, I want its value to be 70.

I have found workaround to above problem by using following line of code.

```
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:70 inSection:indexPath.section] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom  animated:NO];
```

But above line of code stops scroll suddenly. So it appears like scroll is stopped suddenly at Row no.70.

Is there any other solution to implement above problem, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you expect the user to scroll 100 thousand records in a table view?

Comment: yeah, we can expect anything from user, may be he scrolls upto few thousands causing application memory too high, resulting in memory warning.

Comment: That's not very usable. Anyway, what do you expect to happen when the user scrolls up again if you're removing the previous records?

Comment: then definately i will load chunk of 100 records and add them at start of array.

Answer (score 0):

Why not allow the user to access the data in some other way, such as:

1. Search functionality
2. Subcategorisation of data

It's perhaps worth asking, since it's such a large amount of data, is it really likely your user will scroll that far down, and if they have to, will it impact user experience negatively?

For arguments sake, if you wanted to protect your memory use, you would have to dynamically add and remove cells depending on offset. The standard UITableview methods do a pretty good job of doing that for you.

In any case, the number of cells you have allocated at any one time should take into consideration what you are putting into your cells, e.g. images vs. text. If it's images, then 100k is going to lead to a massive application bundle (unless you pull them from your server as needed). If it's text, just go with Apple's own UITableView methods, as they will be more efficient.

But if you're adamant about this approach, and wanted to roll your own custom fix, you could layout a load of UIViews in a UIScrollView, and use the contentOffset of the UIScrollView to know when to add and remove cells. The actual adding of the cells should be done off-screen.

**A.** In scrollViewDidScroll, watch for specific offsets aligned with cellHeights, e.g.

```
if(fabsf(y)%200==0){
   //add new cells below, drop old cells at the top
}
```

as in, if your cells were 50px in height, it would hit this method every 4 cells.

**B.** Update your dynamic indexPath each time new cells are added / old ones are removed. It would be the indexPath of the uppermost cell. Based on that, you can calculate the number of cells currently 'allocated' and the points at which you should pull your cell data from an array:

```
for (int n = dynamicIndexPath; n<dynamicIndexPath+numberOfCells; n++){
   //this is the window onto your data.
}
```

When adding e.g. 4 new cells:

```
for (int n = dynamicIndexPath + numberOfCells-4; n<4; n++){
   //[self layoutNewCellWithData:massiveArray[n] atOffset:y];
}
```

This would be a sort of homegrown UITableview (UIViews in a UIScrollView) where you handle the dequeuing yourself.

But, if it were me, I would look at an alternative way to attack the data, such as via search or some way of splitting the data up into smaller groups. Failing that I would use Apple's UITableView methods, failing that roll my own.